# User friendly urls revelsal

Tags: redirect, yii, routes, friendly-url

Lets say that I want to show  `http://example.com/topic/view/topicname/thenameofthetopic` direclty as `http://example.com/thenameofthetopic`

So I have achieved that when entering `http:// example.com/thenameofthetopic` , it redirects you to the controller/action properly, and the website shows what I want to show, the problem is that of course, the URL changed, and I want it to maintain the format `http://example.com/thenameofthetopic`

Is that possible whitout touching the htaccess file? Just configuring it with yii

How should I do that?

Comment: Take a look at [CUrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly your case is:

```
'components'        => array(
  'urlManager' => array(
      'urlFormat'      => 'path',
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'rules' => array(
          "<name_of_topic:\w+>/" => 'controller/action'
       ),
   ),
)
```

You will get the name of topic in Yii::app()->request->getQuery('name_of_topic');

**htaccess** is Yii - classic, the must be present:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

I would advice you to do another way.

```
'components'        => array(
  'urlManager' => array(
      'urlFormat'      => 'path',
      'showScriptName' => false,
      'rules' => array(
          "t/<name_of_topic:\w+>/" => 'controller/action'
       ),
   ),
)
```

So topic link will be http://www.example.com/t/name_of_topic.
This will allow you to use "a//" for articles etc.

One more thing. Read this article to find much interesting things http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: I modified the htacces before, if I add your line, I get the website without format... this is my actual .htaccess file

RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean saying "get the website without format.."?

Comment: Your htaccess is ok. As written here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url . I hope urlManager settings helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Yesterday was so late and I wasnt able to think clearly... but now I have followed your steps and It works!!!